# Android - error uploading video when file is too large

Tags: java, android, file-upload

In my android app, I'am uploading video files successfully, but if the file is bigger then maybe 10mB, the app crashes and throw me the following exception:

```
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at libcore.net.http.RetryableOutputStream.write(RetryableOutputStream.java:61)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at com.example.kroosky.HttpFileUpload.Sending(HttpFileUpload.java:116)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at com.example.kroosky.HttpFileUpload.Send_Now(HttpFileUpload.java:36)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at com.example.kroosky.VideoUpload.uploadFile(VideoUpload.java:599)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at com.example.kroosky.VideoUpload$getHashTagID.doInBackground(VideoUpload.java:666)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at com.example.kroosky.VideoUpload$getHashTagID.doInBackground(VideoUpload.java:1)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-18 01:18:20.373: E/AndroidRuntime(5131):     ... 4 more
```

Here is my HttpFileUpload class:

```
public class HttpFileUpload implements Runnable{
    URL connectURL;
    String responseString, token, Title, HashTag;
    int Categorie;
    byte[ ] dataToServer;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    HttpFileUpload(String urlString, String vTitle, int vCategorie, String vHash, String token){
            try{
                connectURL = new URL(urlString);
                Title= vTitle;
                Categorie = vCategorie;
                HashTag = vHash;
                this.token = token;

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("HttpFileUpload","URL Malformatted");
            }
    }

    boolean Send_Now(FileInputStream fStream, String fileName){
            fileInputStream = fStream;
            boolean uploadResult = Sending(fileName);

            return uploadResult;
    }

    boolean Sending(String fileName){
            String iFileName = fileName;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            String Tag="fSnd";

            try
            {
                    Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);

                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"videoTitle\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(Title);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"videoCategorie\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(String.valueOf(Categorie));
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"videoHashTag\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(HashTag);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\""+ lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(this.token);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    //int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                    int maxBufferSize = 1024;
                    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                    }
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // close streams
                    fileInputStream.close();

                    dos.flush();

                    Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    // retrieve the response from server
                    int ch;

                    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

                    while( (ch = is.read()) != -1 ){
                        b.append( (char)ch ); 
                    }

                    String s = b.toString();
                    Log.i("Response",s);
                    dos.close();

                    return true; //Upload result

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex){

                Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

                return false; //Upload result

            } catch (IOException ioe){

                Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);

                return false; //Upload result
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And my videoUpload uploadFile function:

```
public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoUpload.this, "", getString(R.string.uploadingVideo), true);
        }
    });

    try {

        videoTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.videoTitleUpload);

        String videoTitleTxt = videoTitle.getText().toString();
        String videoCategorieTxt = categoriesSpinner.getSelectedItem()
                .toString();

        if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("funny")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 0;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("shock")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 1;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("emotion")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 2;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("fail")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 3;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("comedy")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 4;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("sport")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 5;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("fashion")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 6;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("illusion")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 7;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("cars")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 8;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("bikes")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 9;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("music")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 10;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("stars video")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 11;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 12;

        } else if (videoCategorieTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("holidays")) {

            videoCategorieCode = 13;

        }

        final String fileName = sourceFileUri; // File path

        // Set your file path here
        FileInputStream fstrm = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        // Set your server page url (and the file title/description)
        HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload(upLoadServerUri,
                videoTitleTxt, videoCategorieCode, videoHashTagID, token);

        if (hfu.Send_Now(fstrm, fileName)) { // Video successfully uploaded

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.videoUploadOk),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            Intent reloadVideos = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    OnlineVideos.class);
            reloadVideos.putExtra("token", token);
            startActivity(reloadVideos);
            finish();

        } else { // Error uploading video

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.videoUploadError),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error: File not found
    }
} // Close uploadVideo
```

What is wrong ? I've been thinking around this, but I can't understand.
Please help !

Comment: The HTTP library is trying to store your whole upload in memory. I don't know why that is, but hopefully someone else does.

Comment: Thank you. I'll still waiting someone to safe me...

Comment: There seem to be plenty of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately no answers.

Comment: Yes that's it. I've been seeing other questions already, but nothing...